# Making my own container file type

Tags: ios, containers, file-format

I would like to create a file type with a personal extension by combining two other file types, like .mp3 and .pdf.

Later I need to re-open the custom files I've made and be able to use the included files in my app.

How do I do that on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to append the data of the two files together. Include a few bytes of data at the start that tell you the size of each and maybe their original filenames. Then when you want to recreate the two files from the one custom one, you read your header to get the sizes and names, then use that info to recreate the original files.

Another option would be to zip the two files together. Just give the zip file your own custom extension.

Another option would be to use an `NSFileWrapper`. Include the two regular files in the wrapper.